# How to get the Request.Form within a script tag?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

How do I get the `Request.Form` within a script tag?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var sLandingPage = "";
  var sInitContent = "" + Request.Form("textarea") + "";
  var sInitDialogMsg = "";
</script>
```

Comment: why do you want a request.form? If its for accessing some value of a DOM element, then just access it through its id or tag. Thanks

Comment: I am submitting a value from page A to page B

Comment: Request.Form smells of ASP. Is this a client-side JavaScript question, or an ASP (Classic or .NET?) JScript question?

Comment: David it is a asp classic question - but got it solved thanks!

Comment: You might want to add an `asp` tag for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is running at client side, so if your want to get the text area's value before post your page to serve, use this :

```
var sInitContent = document.getElementById("textarea");
```

but if you want to get the posted value of your textarea, (I'm assuming you're using asp or asp.net) try this :

```
var sInitContent = '<%= Request.Form("textarea")%>';
```

Comment: Thanks Canavar - This is actually the solution that I were looking for - I could not figure out why mine were not working cause I have used it a thousand times before - I were requesting a value that did not exists... Request.Form("textarea1") instead of textarea! Thanks

Comment: Text being injected into JavaScript must be suitably escaped, else you have a cross-site-scripting security hole.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do request.form in javascript.  But you can get things out of the query string if you post the form via get.

Answer (score 1):

To read an url parameter from javascript you could use the following method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sLandingPage = '';
var sInitContent = getUrlParam('textarea');
var sInitDialogMsg = '';

function getUrlParam(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
        return '';
    else
        return results[1];
}
</script>
```